# Formula for the coordinate of the midpoint in spherical coordinate system

Tags: euclidean-geometry, spherical-geometry

Please let me know the formula for the coordinate of the midpoint of 2 points in spherical coordinate system .
If possible , I want the answer includes the exact formula as , 
 midpoint = point1 + ( point2 - point1 ) / 2 .

Thank you very much

Thank you very much for the answer. 
Is it necessary to compute the Cartesian coordinate of the midpoint ? No means to compute directly the spherical coordinate of the midpoint ?

Thank you for the second answer . I am happy to know that I must use Cartesian coordinate system for the purpose .

Please someone let me know how to mark the answer as my accepted answer. There is no button for the purpose on my page .

Comment: This will (most-likely) be messy... What you don't like about Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: "No means to compute directly the spherical coordinate of the midpoint?" - Doing coordinate conversions will result in a direct formula. The thing is, spherical coordinates are poorly suited for systems where you need to do translations, segment cuts, and other such operations where Cartesian coordinates are more "natural"...

Comment: FYI - this problem is trivial with Homogeneous Coordinates.

Comment: Hi seven_swodniw: You have two accounts and they must be merged before you can accept an answer. I informed the moderators and they should take care of that soon. These problems will go away when you register.

Comment: To Theo Buehler : Thank you very much . I finally finished to accept the answer .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the general formulas for converting between Cartesian and spherical coordinates to do this:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}r\sin\theta\cos\phi\\r\sin\theta\sin\phi\\r\cos\theta\end{array}\right)\;,$$

so the midpoint between two points $1$ and $2$ is

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1+x_2\\y_1+y_2\\z_1+z_2\end{array}\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{c}r_1\sin\theta_1\cos\phi_1+r_2\sin\theta_2\cos\phi_2\\r_1\sin\theta_1\sin\phi_1+r_2\sin\theta_2\sin\phi_2\\r_1\cos\theta_1+r_2\cos\theta_2\end{array}\right)\;.$$

Then you can substitute this into the expression for the spherical coordinates in terms of the Cartesian coordinates:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}r\\\theta\\\phi\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\\arccos(z/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})\\\arctan(y/x)\end{array}\right)\;.$$

Comment: where arctan still has to be defined properly, such that $\phi \in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @Fabian: correct, depending on the signs of $x$ and $y$; on a computer, this would typically be done using the `atan2` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Heh, I was talking about this the other day... some people have $\phi$ be the longitude and $\theta$ be the co-latitude, while others (me included) use $\theta$ as the longitude and $\phi$ as the co-latitude. So kids, be careful with using spherical coordinate formulae! :)